# How to disable all python linting in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Using the Microsoft Python extension there doesn't appear to be a way to disable linting globally.

I don't mind linting when I am wondering where a typo is that is causing issues, but I certainly don't need it to tell me that the entire code block is bad when I start to add any code that isn't a complete line.

I have disabled every linter I can find in all the settings I can find, here's settings.json for instance:

```
    "python.linting.lintOnSave": false,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.pylintUseMinimalCheckers": false,
    "python.linting.enabled": false
```

I would think that there is a way to completely disable linting globally with one button click, but even just turning it off for python would be enough for me now. Am I asking too much?

Comment: What's the problem? You seem to have already disabled linting?

Comment: That is the problem, with that setting of linting off in everywhere that I can find I still see the error squiggles

Comment: Are your workspace settings overriding your user settings?

Comment: I have even more of them disabled there:
    "python.linting.lintOnSave": false,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.pylintUseMinimalCheckers": false,
    "python.linting.pep8Enabled": false,
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": false,
    "python.linting.mypyEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.pylamaEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.enabled": false,

Comment: I thought I had fixed it by duplicating all the disables in all the settings.json files that I could find, however I still can't kill the linting by default. I might just have to switch to the other vscode python extension

Answer (score 3):

in my case just by going to the setting and searching for `lint python` in the search bar of the setting page and by unchecking the

```
Python > linting: Enabled:
```

[image]
did well and disabled the linting for python scripts!

Comment: I did this and I still have lints all over. Is there something else needed?

Comment: For me it wasn't a setting, I had to disable the `Flake8` extension (there's also a Pylint extension and others).

Comment: I concur - the only thing that works is disabling the `Flake8` extension.

Answer (score 3):

Using VS Code circa v1.78.2, this worked:

- Navigate to Extensions
- Find Pylint, click the gear icon and select Disable
- Find Pylance, click the gear icon and select Disable
- Restart of VS Code was required and disabling both Pylint and Pylance was required

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to disable linter for all languages, but only for Python:

- Find `Linter` extension by Nando Vieira, click the gear icon and select `Extension Settings`
- Click on `Edit in settings.json`
- Find `pylint` inside `linter.linters` and switch `enabled` value to false

Profit!

This method is also suitable for all required languages.